# Rewrite procedure to accept multiple parameters

Tags: vb.net

I wrote the procedure below to handle one specific set of custom controls within my application. However, as my application grew, I find myself using the same procedure over and over for different custom controls in my application.

I have 3 parameters:

1. btnCategoryTabs (custom Control)
2. frmManageStore (original form, but now I have to use on other forms)
3. flpMainPanel (original panel, but now I have more panels that would use the same procedure)

Can this procedure be turned into a Function or parameter Sub? I tried playing with various Dim statements, but nothing worked.

```
    Public Sub removeButtons()

    'This procedure is used to remove buttons from the panel
    'after each category is clicked--

      Dim btnList As List(Of btnCategoryTabs) = frmManageStore.flpMainPanel.Controls.OfType(Of btnCategoryTabs).ToList()

    'Remove these Buttons
    For Each btn As btnCategoryTabs In btnList

        btn.Dispose()

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: that method does take any parameters at all (`removeButtons(no params)`)  You could pass in a param array or even the `List(of MyCtl)` of you wanted.  It is not clear what you mean.

Comment: You are (usually) not supposed to call Dispose directly. What's the purpose of your code?

Comment: @Neolisk I have a procedure that loads buttons for each item on my database on a button click. However, every time the button is clicked the panel fills up with the same items instead of just once. I use the dispose ahead of the fill procedure to prevent double entries from the database

Comment: Then maybe you shouldn't refresh it if items are the same? Can you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: @Neolisk. Thanks, because the question might be off topic, I created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733545/prevent-items-from-loading-more-than-once-for-loop-looks-at-database-and-create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making your code reusable is a good idea. To do that, just pass

- the type of the custom control as a generic parameter and
- the panel as a regular parameter:

  ```
  Public Sub removeButtons(Of TButton As IDisposable)(p As Panel)
      Dim buttons = p.Controls.OfType(Of TButton).ToList()

      For Each btn In buttons
          btn.Dispose()
      Next
  End Sub
  ```

Usage: `removeButtons(Of btnCategoryTabs)(frmManageStore.flpMainPanel)`

*Note that calling `Dispose` on a user interface element looks fishy. You might want to investigate whether what you are doing here is really the right tool for the job. (That might be the subject for another question, though.)*