# Prevent items from loading more than once (For loop looks at database and creates button for each item in database)

Tags: vb.net

I have the following procedure that creates a button for each item on my database:

```
Public Sub AddButtons()

            'Procedure creates a button for each category
        'stored in the database and adds them to the
        'main panel

        Dim ta As New ContactsAndInventoryDataSetTableAdapters.PRODUCT_CATEGORYTableAdapter
        Dim dt As DataTable = ta.GetData


        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

            Dim btn As New btnCategoryTabs()

            btn.lblCategoryName.Name = DirectCast(row("Category_Name"), String)
            btn.lblCategoryName.Text = btn.lblCategoryName.Name
            btn.lblCategoryID.Text = CStr(row("Category_ID"))

            Using STREAM As New MemoryStream(DirectCast(row("image"), Byte()))
                btn.picPCategoryPicture.Image = Image.FromStream(STREAM)
            End Using

            'Add categories to the Panel
            frmManageStore.flpMainPanel.Controls.Add(btn)

        Next

End Sub
```

That works well, however, every time user clicks the button my panel duplicates my items since the procedure runs again.  To prevent that I wrote the following:

```
    Public Sub removeButtons()

    'This procedure is used to remove buttons from the panel
    'after each category is clicked--

       Dim btnList As List(Of btnCategoryTabs) = frmManageStore.flpMainPanel.Controls.OfType(Of btnCategoryTabs).ToList()

    'Remove these Buttons
    For Each btn As btnCategoryTabs In btnList

        btn.Dispose()

    Next

End Sub
```

My click on the button event is a follows:

```
    Private Sub btnCategories_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCategories.Click

    PublicSubs.removeButtons()
    PublicSubs.addCategories()

End Sub
```

[On a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732437/rewrite-procedure-to-accept-multiple-parameters) some of the users recommended not using `.Dispose` So my question is, is there a better way keep my items from duplicating if the user clicks on the button more than once.  The picture below shows what happens when the user clicks the Category button more than once and the `PublicSubs.removeButtons()` does not run.

[image]

Comment: See [Memory Leak](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4083344)  also [What are Parking Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20585012) and [Adding / removing controls](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20584480).  Since the control seems to include a bitmap, you should be sure the control release those resources when it is being disposed of.  You dont *normally* dispose of controls because the form will do that for you when it is closed/disposed, but if you are creating and removing them, you should (*must* according to Mr Passant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply call `frmManageStore.flpMainPanel.Controls.Clear()` in order to remove all the buttons from the panel.

Note that `btn.Dispose()` indeed removes the button from the `Controls` collection; however this is not obvious and can be considered of being a [side effect](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect) of the `Dispose` method. Therefore preferably remove the button explicitly. This makes your intention clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Right after `Public Sub AddButtons()` add:

```
frmManageStore.flpMainPanel.Controls.Clear()
```

That will clear out the existing controls before adding new ones, thus eliminating your duplicate items.

Comment: Also should mention, you might want to do a Try/Catch block around your code.  In that case, you would want to put `frmManageStore.flpMainPanel.Controls.Clear()` after `Dim dt As DataTable = ta.GetData` and before your For... so that if your data call fails, you don't blow away all your items and have nothing to show for it.